# Sqlite database  file is getting encrypted or is not a database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I have no idea what was the problem is in my program. When run this select code for fetching  data from   SQlite in my program, the first time it crashes with this error message:

> kill error while killing target (killing anyway):
>   warning: error on line 2179 of "/SourceCache/gdb/gdb-1510/src/gdb/macosx/macosx-nat-inferior.c" in function "macosx_kill_inferior_safe": (os/kern) failure (0x5x)
>   quit

Here's my insert code:

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];

    sqlite3 *database;

    NSMutableArray *locations;
    NSString *result = nil;
    NSString *dbPath = [self getWritableDBPath];

    if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        NSString *sqlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select Longitude,Latitude from myLocation"];
        const char *sqlStatement = [sqlStr UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            locations = [NSMutableArray array];

            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                double longitude = sqlite3_column_double(compiledStatement, 0);
                double latitude = sqlite3_column_double(compiledStatement, 1);
                NSLog(@"%f , %f",longitude,latitude);
                NSString *coords = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f,%f\n",longitude,latitude] autorelease];

                [locations addObject:coords];
                NSLog(@"this location :-%@",locations);
                //[coords release];

            }

            result = [locations componentsJoinedByString:@","]; // same as `fake_location`
            NSLog(@"this for resulte data :- %@",result);
            // Get file path here

            NSError *error;
            if ( [result writeToFile:dbPath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error] ) {
                NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);


    pointsArray = [[result componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] retain];
    pointsArrayIndex = 0;
    oldLocationsIndex = 0;

    [result release];

    oldLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    return self;
}
```

The second time I run my application, it shows me that on the console:

> Save Error: file is encrypted or is not a database

What do these errors mean, and how do I solve that?

Comment: do you want to fire insert query in sqlite?????

Comment: Yes My friend I need the sqlite insert statement

Comment: you are trying to overwrite entire database file with NSData, you can not do that, check my answer below, you only need to fire insert query...

Comment: @jignesh Actually i am trying to fetch data not for inserting data.When I run 1st time after writting the select code then give me error And when run 2nd time it give me  Save Error: file is encrypted or is not a database

Comment: Can you debug dbPath what it gives??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fire insert query using following:

```
-(void)insertLocation:(double)latitude withLongitude:(double)longitude
{
sqlite3_stmt *insertStatement = nil;
const char *sql = "insert into UserJourneyLocation(Latitude, Longitude) Values(?,?)";
int returnValue = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &insertStatement, NULL);
if(returnValue == SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqlite3_bind_double(insertStatement,1,latitude);
            sqlite3_bind_double(insertStatement,2,longitude);
    if(sqlite3_step(insertStatement)==SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        //Data;
    }
}
sqlite3_finalize(insertStatement);
}
```

Comment: Sorry my friend I doing the select statement not the insert statemt sorry Check updata question please

Comment: but you can not write data into databse using [result writeToFile:dbPath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error], can you mention why this line has been used??

Comment: I comment that line It work but now Show me next error like that -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xe2db5f0.

Comment: Thanks it work but When should i write that [result writeToFile:dbPath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error] And What's the use .When to use that

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have.

Go to iphone application document folder

/users/(yourname)/library/application support/iphone simulator/user/application

And remove all Targets.After that Restart your application.

Comment: No my friend it sitll show me Save Error: file is encrypted or is not a database